# Using IF formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was just wondering how I could use an IF formula in VBA. This is the formula that I currently have, but it is giving me the error.."End of Statement"

```
Range("a10").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row
For i = 10 To lastrow
Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("Z" & i).Formula = _
"=IF(ABS("Y" & i)>400,""CHECK"","""")"
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What's the formula supposed to look like without the doubled quotes?

Comment: It's supposed to be an IF statement of =IF(ABS("Y")>400,"CHECK","")

Comment: I'm trying to get the whole column of Y starting from Y10 which is why I used i = 10

Comment: double quotes can be replaced by chr(34) wich is easier to read. For example `.Formula = "TextBegin" & chr(34) & "Other Text" & chr(34)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you need to do:

```
Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("Z" & i).Formula = _
"=IF(ABS(Y" & i & ")>400,""CHECK"","""")"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Range("a10").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row
For i = 10 To lastrow
Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("Z" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ABS(R1C" & i &")>400,""CHECK"","""")"
```

Comment: I used this, but the formula comes up as #NAME? and shows "Y"&i in the cell instead of Y10,Y11,Y12.....

Comment: That will give you "Y"10 (for example) so it won't work

Comment: My mistake, I have modified it to fix