# VBA Excel autoincrement of cell number in the formula when new worksheets are added

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I would like to make the formula auto change when the new sheet is added.
The cell values are going to change every 13 steps roughly and they appear in the excel IF statement.
As you can see in the picture below I would like to have the 13 step increment, as the formulas will be referred to the cells located every 13 steps lower in the NIM & BADGER sheet.
In the sheet CAB1 this is G33, in the sheet CAB2 it should be G46, in the sheet CAB3 - G59 and so forth...

[image]

My formula is based on IF statement, so it can be written in VBA as per the solution here:

[Using IF formula in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395900/using-if-formula-in-vba)

Next, I need the cell change every 13 steps. I found some similar problems & solutions here:

[Increment excel formula by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439405/increment-excel-formula-by-1)

[Increment value on multiple worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638897/increment-value-on-multiple-worksheets)

I tried to write it in the following code:

```
 Sub Value()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim xNumber As Long, xValue As Long
 Dim xName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set ws = Sheets("CAB1")
 xNumber = Sheets("NIM & BADGER").Range("R27").Value
 xValue = 33

 For i = 1 To Number
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "CAB" & i + 1
 Sheets("CAB" & i + 1).Range("E43").Formula = "=IF('NIM & BADGER'!G" & xValue + (13 * i) & "=0,"",'NIM & BADGER'!G" & xValue + (13 * i) & ")"
 Next

 ws.Activate

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

I have got an error:
**Application-defined or object-defined error**

with debugger pointing the following line:

```
  Sheets("CAB" & i + 1).Range("E43").Formula = "=IF('NIM & BADGER'!G" & xValue + (13 * i) & "=0,"",'NIM & BADGER'!G" & xValue + (13 * i) & ")"
```

How can I change these formulas (the cell numbers) automatically when adding one or more worksheets?

Any help cordially appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have played a bit with the quotes, but the result remains the same...

```
   Sheets("CAB" & i + 1).Range("E43").Formula = "=IF('NIM & BADGER'!G" & xValue + (13 * i) & "=0,'','NIM & BADGER'!G" & xValue + (13 * i) & "')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* write it as a formula. It is not really pretty though, but it would work:

> =IF(OFFSET('NIM & BADGER'!$G$1,(NUMBERVALUE(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+4,255))*13)+19,0,1,1)=0,"",OFFSET('NIM & BADGER'!$G$1,(NUMBERVALUE(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+4,255))*13)+19,0,1,1))

EDIT: To make your VBA code work. Try this:

```
 Sub Value()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim xNumber As Long, xValue As Long
 Dim xName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set ws = Sheets("CAB1")
 xNumber = Sheets("NIM & BADGER").Range("R27").Value
 xValue = 33

 For i = 1 To xNumber
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "CAB" & i + 1
 Sheets("CAB" & i + 1).Range("E43").Formula = "=IF('NIM & BADGER'!G" & xValue + (13 * i) & "=0,"""",'NIM & BADGER'!G" & xValue + (13 * i) & ")"
 Next

 ws.Activate

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

As I tried to explain below, you had two issues:

1. In your 'For' statement, you forgot a 'x' in front of 'Number', so
   you didn't refer to your variable.
2. When quoting double quotes in VBA, you need to wrap them in double quotes. So the true case of your IF statement has to look like """".

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Yes, but it looks like this formula needs to be typed manually in every sheet. I need something automatic, asI might have up to 20 sheets to cover.

Comment: Sort of true. I reckoned you would copy the CAB# sheet to have CAB1, CAB2... CABn, as illustrated in your screen dump. In that case you will not have to retype the formula. You just add it to the first sheet, then duplicate the sheet and as long as you stick to the naming convention (CAB + numbers) and name them in an ascending order (to avoid skipping 13 lines), then you don't have to touch the formula. But of course, if you had a different process in mind then I need the to understand it to assist.

Comment: OK, My idea looks as follows:
On the sheet CAB1, my formula is =IF('NIM & BADGER'!G33=0,"",'NIM & BADGER'!G33)".
On the CAB2 I need:
=IF('NIM & BADGER'!G46=0,"",'NIM & BADGER'!G46)"
On the CAB3;
NIM & BADGER'!G59=0,"",'NIM & BADGER'!G59)
...and so on. As you can see, the cells increments on 13 steps. I can't type them manually because the sheets are going to be removed and added over and over again. I need the code, which will automatically increase these values as the new sheet is added.

Comment: If you stick to this naming convention, the formula will work. The formula takes the number after "CAB" and return the value in the cell that is 13*[the number] + 19 rows below G1 in the NIM & BADGER sheet (unless it is 0, in which case it returns ""). I.e. CAB1= 13*1+19 = 32 below G1 = G33. CAB2= 13*2+19 = 45 below G1= G46, CAB3 = 13*3+19 = 58 below G1 = G59, etc...

Comment: Your formula is not working, unfortunately. Are you able to give me a hint in the VBA code?

Comment: Sure. But where is the fun in that? :o) ... Your 'Number' is wrong. It should be 'xNumber': "For i = 1 To **xNumber**" And the double quotes in the formula should be double-double quotes: as ...* i) & "=0,**""""**,'NIM & BADGER... Or you could just put the formula above in E43 of CAB1 and skip the whole line :o)... Btw: I don't think your macro ever got to the formula line due to the Number issue. Next time, try stepping through the macro step-by-step by pressing F8.

Comment: To be hones I am not clued up enough to deduct the solution from your suggestions. Could you write the code snippet when possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thak you! It's valid now!
Only question, why should be 4 quotes instead of 2? 
xValue + (13 * i) & "=0,"""",'NIM & BADGER'!G"
(13 * i) & "=0,"",'NIM & BADGER'!G"
It looks like I was very close, but missed these 2 quotes then. COuld you explain me?

Comment: Because if you only use 2 quotes, VBE will see it as two strings being split - VBE cannot tell whether you are ending a string or quoting double quote. So it sees it as 1 sentence: "=0," and another sentence: ",'NIM & BADGER'!G", with no operator in between, which is why it errs, btw.. Hence, you need to escape the double quote, and one way to do that is by quoting the double quotes... hence """"

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. It will be definitely helpful for the future because I guess I will parse the other formulas in VBA too.